# Getting "ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded" when passing query parameter to BigQuery CLI

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm sending a query with query parameter to BigQuery. The simplified query is like:

```
bq query --nouse_legacy_sql \
--parameter='my_query_param:ARRAY<STRUCT<x INT64, y INT64>>:[STRUCT(90 as x, 1 as y), STRUCT(95 as x, 10 as y)]' \
'SELECT @my_query_param'
```

But BQ CLI just crashed with error:

```
== Error trace ==
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/cygdrive/c/Users/Andrew/AppData/Local/Google/Cloud SDK/google-cloud-sdk/platform/bq/bq.py", line 1105, in RunSafely
    return_value = self.RunWithArgs(*args, **kwds)
  File "/cygdrive/c/Users/Andrew/AppData/Local/Google/Cloud SDK/google-cloud-sdk/platform/bq/bq.py", line 1982, in RunWithArgs
    kwds['query_parameters'] = _ParseParameters(self.parameter)
  File "/cygdrive/c/Users/Andrew/AppData/Local/Google/Cloud SDK/google-cloud-sdk/platform/bq/bq.py", line 5620, in _ParseParameters
    results.append(_ParseParameter(param_string))
  File "/cygdrive/c/Users/Andrew/AppData/Local/Google/Cloud SDK/google-cloud-sdk/platform/bq/bq.py", line 5626, in _ParseParameter
    type_dict, value_dict = _ParseParameterTypeAndValue(param_string)
  File "/cygdrive/c/Users/Andrew/AppData/Local/Google/Cloud SDK/google-cloud-sdk/platform/bq/bq.py", line 5639, in _ParseParameterTypeAndValue
    return type_dict, _ParseParameterValue(type_dict, value_string)
  File "/cygdrive/c/Users/Andrew/AppData/Local/Google/Cloud SDK/google-cloud-sdk/platform/bq/bq.py", line 5718, in _ParseParameterValue
    value_input = json.loads(value_input)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 339, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 364, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 382, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

What should I do to pass query parameter with BQ CLI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the query work by using:

```
bq query --nouse_legacy_sql \
--parameter='my_query_param:ARRAY<STRUCT<x INT64, y INT64>>:[{"x":90,"y": 1}, {"x":95,"y": 10}]' \
'SELECT @my_query_param'
```

Note that query parameter value is passed in as JSON format: `[{"x":90,"y": 1}, {"x":95,"y": 10}]` instead of SQL literal.

Couple of examples are also available in [public documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/parameterized-queries#bigquery_query_params_arrays-cli).